# Multiple file-input with Angular Dynamic Form

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups

**TLDR: How to use FormArray or FormGroup with multiple file-input fields?**

Hello everyone,

I want to build an event manager with Angular. Each event has a title, description, image and a flyer. The image is a png or jpg file-input and the flyer is a pdf one.

I need a toolbar performing the following actions:

[image: toolbar]

- add should append a new event to the list withouth image or pdf
- delete should remove all selected event
- save should update to the database the event and load the two file-inputs files.

The list of event look like:

[image: event]

But I struggle to implement the form.

**How can I use multiple file-input into a dynamic form with angular?**

This is what I tried to do (event = promotion):

**HTML**:

```
  <form [formGroup]="promotionForm" *ngFor="let promotion of promotions; let i = index;">
    <div class="card" *ngIf="promotion.displayed" (click)="promotion.selected = !promotion.selected;">
      <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="promotion.title" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Subtitle</h2>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="promotion.subtitle" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Language</h2>
        <mat-select [(value)]="promotion.language"></mat-select>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <textarea matInput cdkAutosizeMinRows="5" [(ngModel)]="promotion.description"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="img">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Image</h2>
          <mat-form-field>
            <ngx-mat-file-input formControlName="image" [multiple]="false" accept="image/webp, image/jpeg, image/png">
              <mat-icon ngxMatFileInputIcon>folder</mat-icon>
            </ngx-mat-file-input>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <img src="{{promotion.image}}">
      </div>
      <div class="pdf">
        <h2>PDF</h2>
        <mat-form-field>
          <ngx-mat-file-input formControlName="pdf" [multiple]="false" accept="application/pdf">
            <mat-icon ngxMatFileInputIcon>folder</mat-icon>
          </ngx-mat-file-input>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <mat-checkbox class="checkbox" [checked]="promotion.selected"></mat-checkbox>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**TS**:

```
promotions: Promotion[] = [];
  maxSize: number = 2; //Mo
  promotionForm: FormGroup;
  images: any[];
  pdfs: any[];

  constructor(private promotionService: PromotionService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.promotionForm = this.fb.group({
      image: [MaxSizeValidator(this.maxSize * 1024 * 1024)],
      pdf: [MaxSizeValidator(this.maxSize * 1024 * 1024)]
    })
    this.getAllPromotions();
  }

  getAllPromotions() {
    this.promotionService.getAllPromotions()
      .subscribe(promotions => {
        this.promotions = promotions.reverse();
        this.promotions.map(p => {
          p.selected = false;
          p.displayed = true;
        })
      })
  }

  deletePromotions() {
    let toDelete$ = this.promotions.filter(p => p.selected).map(p => { return this.promotionService.deletePromotion(p._id) });
    forkJoin(toDelete$).subscribe(() => this.getAllPromotions());
  }

  updatePromotions() {
    let toUpdate$ = this.promotions.filter(p => p.selected).map(p => { return this.promotionService.updatePromotion(p) });
    forkJoin(toUpdate$).subscribe(() => this.getAllPromotions());
  }

  selectAll() {
    if (this.promotions.filter(p => p.displayed).every(p => p.selected)) {
      this.promotions.map(p => p.selected = false)
    } else {
      this.promotions.filter(p => p.displayed).map(p => p.selected = true)
    }
  }
```

The issue with this solution is to get a unique file for each event. I want an unique file-input for each event and if I use FormGroup, I'm unable to have n file-input associated to each event. Should I use FormArrays of FormGroup and use image and pdf into each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I achieved it.

Instead of using formArray. I added a custom control for each objects. Here's my html

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="promotion.filesForm">
        <div class="img">
          <div class="container">
            <h2>Image</h2>
            <mat-form-field>
              <ngx-mat-file-input formControlName="image" [multiple]="false" accept="image/webp, image/jpeg, image/png" (change)="promotion.image=''">
                <mat-icon ngxMatFileInputIcon>folder</mat-icon>
              </ngx-mat-file-input>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <img src="{{promotion.image}}">
        </div>
        <div class="pdf">
          <h2>PDF</h2>
          <mat-form-field>
            <ngx-mat-file-input formControlName="pdf" [multiple]="false" accept="application/pdf">
              <mat-icon ngxMatFileInputIcon>folder</mat-icon>
            </ngx-mat-file-input>
          </mat-form-field>
          <a href="{{promotion.pdf}}">Flyer</a>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
```

And my ts

```
  addPromotionFileForm() {
    const fileForm = new FormGroup({
      image: new FormControl('', [MaxSizeValidator(this.maxSize * 1024 * 1024)]),
      pdf: new FormControl('', [MaxSizeValidator(this.maxSize * 1024 * 1024)])
    });
    return fileForm as FormGroup;
  }

  getAllPromotions() {
    this.promotionService.getAllPromotions()
      .subscribe(promotions => {
        this.promotions = promotions.reverse();
        this.promotions.map(p => {
          p.selected = false;
          p.displayed = true;
          p.filesForm = this.addPromotionFileForm();
        })
      })
  }
```

When I want to upload them, I do a deep copy of my events array and I put the file into the image and pdf attributes.

```
  updatePromotions() {
    let payload = cloneDeep(this.promotions);
    payload.map(p => {
      p.image = p.filesForm.value.image;
      p.pdf = p.filesForm.value.pdf;
      delete p.filesForm;
    });
    let toUpdate$ = payload.filter(p => p.selected).map(p => { return this.promotionService.updatePromotion(p) });
    forkJoin(toUpdate$).subscribe(() => this.getAllPromotions());
  }
```

Then I send them with my http service ensuring to pass the file with the FormData way and giving the good http headers ! (you must control that your api accept the header `enctype`

```
  updatePromotion(promotion: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(promotion).forEach(key => formData.append(key, promotion[key]));
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': this.auth
      })
    };
    return this.http.put<any>(this.apiUrl, formData, httpOptions);
  }
```

Finally, my backend api take care of the database storage:

First the route

```
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const multer = require('../middleware/multer');
const promotionController = require('../controller/promotion-controller');

const promotionUpload = [{
    name: 'image',
    maxCount: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'pdf',
    maxCount: 1
  }
];
router.put('/', auth, multer.fields(promotionUpload), promotionController.updatePromotion);
```

Then the controller

```
exports.updatePromotion = (req, res) => {
  let payload = {
    ...req.body
  };

  // If req contains files
  if (req.files) {
    if (req.files['pdf']) {
      payload.pdf = req.protocol + "://" + req.get('host') + "/" + req.files['pdf'][0].path;
    }
    if (req.files['image']) {
      payload.image = req.protocol + "://" + req.get('host') + "/" + req.files['image'][0].path;
    }
  }

  // Update database
  Promotion.findByIdAndUpdate(payload._id, payload)
    .then(() => res.status(200).json("Success"))
    .catch((error) => res.status(500).json("Failure: " + error))
}
```

This is it! I used several day to solve this puzzle and I'm proud to show you a working solution. Dont hesitate to ask question. I would be happy to help